# Create variable execution time Java

Tags: java, variables

Is possible to do in Java something like this? :

- System.out.... -> ask for a string
- Store this string
- Create a variable with the name of this string

Thank you very much!

Comment: how can `System.out...` ask for a string?

Comment: No, Java doesn't support dynamic naming. Use a map instead.

Comment: @Blip OP means "please insert a String".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You cannot create a variable, at execution time, with a particular name.

However, you can use a [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html), which probably does what you want. The `get` method will look up an entry, and the `put` method will set an entry. Example:

```
Map<String, Integer> myMapOfThings = new HashMap<>();

String nameOfThing = /* ... get a string from the user somehow here ... */;
myMapOfThings.put(nameOfThing, 2);

System.out.println(myMapOfThings.get(nameOfThing)); // prints 2
```

Comment: There's probably some conceited way using reflection, but why would anyone want to go through that trouble...

Comment: ok thanks! now, another thing, can you do with only one instanciated hashmap more than one put? : `myMap.put(name,2); myMap.put(name2,3);`  yes, right? Thanks!

Comment: @hadolfo Yes. And it will remember both, and you can get either one at any time. Kind of like an array with strings as indexes.